# Audio and Hyperlink Together in HTML?

Tags: html

I am trying to display both audio and a hyperlink, yet only the audio is shown. The hyperlink worked when I commented out the audio portion, yet I can't get them to work together. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
<audio controls autoplay loop src="/audio/tuba.mp3">
<a href="zvideo.html" target=_blank>
   To Video!
</a>
```

Comment: Maybe try closing your audio tag first? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#usage_notes